# Export PDF to Word - Table issues

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, tables

I have created a document in Indesign, saved it as a PDF (Interactive - RGB) and exported the PDF as a word document.

However after exporting as a Word Doc one of the table cells has resized. It only happens on the one table cell and isn't there on the PDF or INDD file.

How do I go about fixing this cell?

Issue is with "Domain Age" height

[image: PDF]

[image: Word Doc]

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few things going on. The white line between domain age and site map suggests to me it might not even be a table (sometimes word will interpret things like this as text boxes or shapes).

- On the **Table Layout** tab, click **View Gridlines** to help diagnose where the issues are
- Reset table formatting by highlighting the entire table and then, on the **Table Design** click **Clear**
- Reset text formatting by selecting it, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (to remove character-level formatting) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to remove paragraph level formatting.
- Click around, especially on the shaded cells. Are those *really* cell backgrounds, or are they shapes anchored behind the cell?

PDF to Word import should always be a last resort. If someone asks me to send them an "editable" version of a file created in InDesign, I usually copy-paste the main text frame from InDesign into Word and just explain the formatting is done separately.